# Is there a way to disable touch temporarily?

Tags: touchscreen

Imagine that you want to do something, while the display in is action (not in sleep mode) and at the same time, you don't want to do anything else. This situation is like **children lock**, in which, all buttons fail to react, temporarily, to disable any kind of interaction by a child.

Is there a way to achieve this in Android? Do we have something like **lock screen**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your talking within your app, this is impossible as you cannot override the home button even if it is soft or hard button. So a full lock is always impossible.

This is to stop rogue app's taking full control of the phone.

Comment: Actually the built-in camera app can do this. If you press the power button while in the camera app it locks all other buttons and the touch-screen, while still showing the screen display. However, I have no idea if 3rd party apps can do this or if it's only available to system apps to prevent rogue apps misusing the feature.

Comment: What device is this? Pressing power on the N1 whilst in the camera app - does the usual - locks the phone and turns the screen black.

Comment: Galaxy S with official Gingerbread, only found it by accident a couple of weeks ago when I was taking a few pictures in a row and then suddenly none of the buttons worked. Hadn't looked into whether it was stick or a Samsung TouchWiz change, but either way it shows this is possible for a system app.

Comment: Yeah well it makes sense for system apps, as the 'lock screen' itself is a system app :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are several apps on Google Play that can do that, such as, [TouchBlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker).

Comment: Does anyone know which Android SDK APIs can be used to achieve such kind of Touch Blocking?